# Obtain all filenames in a directory using vim

Tags: file, vim, directory, filenames

This is the algorithm of the code:

```
for every *file* in a directory
  nnoremap ,*file* <C-o>:read $HOME/*file*
end
```

So the problem is, I don't know how to code the "for every *file* in a directory".

PS: I am new to vim and I don't know if it's possible

Comment: what exactly do you try to do? This makes no sense. What is your end goal to achieve with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`glob()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#glob%28%29) function. -> `glob($HOME.'/*')`

I'm not sure this is a good idea, but hey, who am I to judge? :)

Comment: While I think this is indeed the answer he deserves, i do not think it is the answer he needs. Honestly i do not see how glob should help him, to ?remap C-o per file? to write the filename ???  okay i give up I think you see my point

Answer (score 1):

Apart from `glob()` (see answer from @LucHermitte), you also need `:execute`:

```
execute 'nnoremap ,' . file . ' <C-o>:read $HOME/' . file
```

(or more elegantly with `printf()`:)

```
execute printf('nnoremap ,%s <C-o>:read $HOME/%s', file, file)
```

#### Description

Vimscript is evaluated exactly like the Ex commands typed in the `:` command-line. There were no variables in `ex`, so there's no way to specify them. When typing a command interactively, you'd probably use `<C-R>=` to insert variable contents:

```
:sleep <C-R>=timetowait<CR>m<CR>
```

... but in a script, `:execute` must be used. All the literal parts of the Ex command must be quoted (single or double quotes), and then concatenated with the variables:

```
execute 'sleep' timetowait . 'm'
```